# How to add authentication to an exposed endpoint in Azure Bot Service?

Tags: rest, authentication, bots, azure-bot-service

I am working on a NodeJS Notification Bot with Restify Server that has an exposed endpoint for receiving POST messages from an external service. How can I add authentication to this endpoint? I have seen some examples of authentication, but none of them seem to clarify which keys to use and how to use them. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

This bot was created from the default notification bot template in Teams App Toolkit.

[doubts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmY1N.png)

I found some secrets in direct line configuration page but I dont know how to automatically import them into the bot so I can check for it in the header, if that is even how it must be done. I also couldnt find the documentation related to App Service Extension Keys, which are available on the same page.